# The option --install-recommends is not recognized by APT

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to install [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) on [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus), but it gives me this error:

> \E: Command line option `--install-recommends` is not understood in combination with the other options

What can I do to make this work?

The code is:

```
sudo apt-get --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

Answer (score 5):

I think, you forgot the 'install' parameter.

What you wrote:

```
sudo apt-get --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

What you should've written (per APT's syntax):

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

Though I think APT still defaults to your wanted behavior.

So omitting the `--install-recommends` would've been fine:

```
sudo apt-get install winehq-devel
```